# Are C pointer's created on demand?

Tags: c, pointers

In C, we have data, and we have pointers. Pointers by themselves are binary data. So, at the hardware level there is no difference between data and pointers. Pointers must be an implementation. If we have a variable, that variable has two properties, the data and the address, which itself is a data, in a sense this creates an infinite pointer loop kind of thing. Since every pointer is a data, they must have a pointer that points to them, and the pointer that points to the pointer must have a pointer, and so on.

This type of implementation would only make sense if pointers are created on demand. Let's say we create a variable called `a`, does C immediately assign a pointer to this variable right after the variable being declared? Or is it when I explicitly try to pull the pointer by doing `&a` that C creates a pointer according to some internal algorithm?

Comment: "that variable has two properties, the data and the pointer," no, it has a value and an adress. And you can have a pointer that holds that adress as value.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number yes but what's storing that address then?

Comment: Furthermore, my question in the second section of the post still holds

Comment: If the variable is an automatic (local) variable, it might be referenced by an offset from a base pointer. So all those variables in any one function have the same pointer. In this case the pointer is created on demand, since the same function may be called from different heirarchies of function (or by recursion).

Comment: _"Every pointer must have a parent pointer"_: no, this is not true. Pointers are not created automatically. If you need to use a pointer _you_ declare a pointer and then you use it.

Comment: From C point of view there is no pointer when you do stuff like `int a;` There is only an object of type `int` that can be referenced using `a`. How it's done at machine level is not described by C

Comment: *Every pointer must have a parent pointer.*  Really?  How many street addresses does a building have?  Do street addresses have to have street addresses that have street addresses *ad infinitum*?

Comment: The compiler keeps the address of identifiers in its internal workspace. The generated executable code uses the "address" directly from the opcode (no lookup): `a += b;` might output something like `add [SP - 8], [SP - 4]` <== no lookup for `a` or `b`.

Comment: The variable might not even *have* a memory address: it might be in a processor register.

Comment: There are pointer *expressions*, pointer *values*, and pointer *variables*.

Comment: IMHO you have a little mesh about what a pointer is.  From that point out any reasoning you do can be wrong, misoriented or simply be false.  You make a lot of reasoning chain before any conclussions, and many of your steps are simply false. So, please, fix your actual question to ask something simple that can be simple to answer.

Answer (score 4):

> in a sense this creates an infinite pointer loop kind of thing. Every pointer must have a parent pointer

This is logically incorrect. It's like saying: "A pointer is a street address. Every person has a street address. Therefore a street address is a pointer."

Pointers are variables containing addresses, but that doesn't make addresses pointers... something can have an address without a pointer used to access that address. Just like your machine code can contain integer values without them being stored in `int` variables.

> Or is it when I explicitly try to pull the pointer by doing &a that C creates a pointer according to some internal algorithm?

Yes, kind of. Here the address is actually *used* by the program so the `&a` address must be stored somewhere. You can think of it as a temporary pointer variable if it helps. In practice, if we disassemble this code:

```
int a;
printf("%p\n", &a);
```

Then on gcc x86 this just results in a "load effective address" instruction. That is, the compiler stores the address in a register which is then passed on to `printf` as per that function's calling convention.

Comment: So you mean data can be in memory without having an address?

Comment: @aNoNyMoUs No, data can be in memory without having a pointer variable referring to it. Again, common sense: if pointers are variables containing addresses, then that _does not make addresses pointers_.

Comment: Please confirm my assumption. In memory, we have two bytes, byte1 and byte2. Creating a pointer creates a mapping between byte1 and byte2 where byte1 is the address and byte2 is the value. Is this correct?

Comment: @aNoNyMoUs I don't understand what you mean with that, but it doesn't sound correct.

Comment: @aNoNyMoUs This is incorrect. Each byte has a physical location on the RAM chip. The location doesn't have to be stored anywhere, because it exists in the real world. The number in pointer is "street address" which the controller of the RAM chip uses to find the physical location.

Answer (score 2):

Your description is all wrong. It seems you are confusing C pointers and memory addresses at execution time. It's completely different things.

Pointers in C are no different from other data types. You get a pointer to type T only when you define one, i.e. like `T* p;` Just like you only get an `int` object when you define one (e.g. `int a;`).

At machine level it's completely different. In order to access objects (aka variables) stored in memory, the CPU needs a way to calculate the address of that object. The C standard does **not** care how it's done. It's an implementation detail that may differ from system to system.

Many implementations uses a "stack pointer" (stored in a CPU register) as reference for other variables. Instead of knowing the exact address of an object, the address is found as "value of stack pointer" plus an offset (i.e. SP+offset). This offset is then hardcoded into the execution binary, i.e. the instruction set of the CPU can have an instruction that do stuff like: "Read the memory at address SP+fixed_offset and store it in register X".

Take a look at this simple (and rather stupid) function:

```
unsigned long foo(unsigned long x)
{
    unsigned long y = x;
    putchar('a');
    return y + x;
}
```

This defines two "unsigned long" objects and return their sum. Using godbolt.org, gcc 11.2, and flag -fomit-frame-pointer (no optimization to keep things simple), I get this machine code (with my comments added):

```
foo:
    sub     rsp, 40                 // Change stack pointer to reserve 40 bytes

    mov     QWORD PTR [rsp+8], rdi  // Save the passed value (i.e. register rdi)
                                    // in object x at memory address rsp+8

    mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rsp+8]  // Read object x into register rax
    mov     QWORD PTR [rsp+24], rax // Save rax in object y at memory address rsp+24
                                    // So this is really y = x

    mov     edi, 97                 // These are just
    call    putchar                 // putchar('a');

    mov     rdx, QWORD PTR [rsp+24] // Read object y into register rdx
    mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rsp+8]  // Read object x into register rax
    add     rax, rdx                // rax = rax + rdx, i.e. rax = y + x

    add     rsp, 40                 // Restore stack pointer, i.e. release
                                    // the 40 bytes

    ret                             // Return. The returned value is in register rax
```

So on this specific system the memory address of `x` is found as "stack pointer + 8" and the memory address of `y` is found as "stack pointer + 24".  From the machine code we can't tell the actual memory address of the variables as it depends on the value of the stack pointer (rsp) when the function is called.

The lesson is that - yes, at machine level there is a way to get the memory address of `x` and `y` but there is no such thing as an automatically created and stored pointer to any of them.

Now for fun - the same code compiled with -O2 gives:

```
foo:
    push    rbx
    mov     rsi, QWORD PTR stdout[rip]
    mov     rbx, rdi
    mov     edi, 97
    call    putc
    lea     rax, [rbx+rbx]
    pop     rbx
    ret
```

Take a look at the code and see if you can find `x` and `y` ;-)

(but - to repeat - all this is not described by the C standard, it's just how it's done on this specific system).

**BTW** Also be aware that objects/variables define by the C code may exist only in CPU registers, i.e. the are never written to memory and consequently they don't even have an address.

Answer (score 1):

Every variable is stored in the memory . The address (pointer) is not stored separately, it is simply the location of the variable.

*(This is actually more complex than that: Some variables might normally stay in processor registers instead of RAM, but if you take their address, the compiler might store them in memory so that the address can be taken. Or if you just print the address, it might invent a fake address for them.)*

If you take the address of a variable and store it in a pointer, you create a new variable, and assign the value of the address of the other variable. But the address of this new variable is not stored separately, it is simply the location of the variable.

There is no "infinite pointer loop", unless your code makes infinite number of variables and your computer has infinite memory.

What determines the address then? How does the program know where the variable is stored?

This is controlled by the operating system, which gives your program memory blocks based on the memory allocations you make. Your program determines (at compile time) which variable is in which address relative to this memory block.

Comment: "Every variable is stored in the memory." Actually not. Variables can't exist solely in registers.

Answer (score 1):

I would not say "we have data, and we have pointers".  Yes, pointers are different, but saying it this way doesn't really capture what's different about them.

Any variable has a *location* (also called an *address*), and a *value* (perhaps also called "contents").  If you say

```
int i = 5;
```

the value is 5, and we're not precisely sure where the location is (because we usually don't care), although the identifier `i` helps us keep track of it, whatever it is.  But there are definitely two things, the location or address, and the contents or value.

If you say

```
int *ip = &i;
```

once again you have a variable named `ip`, and a value, which in this case is a pointer, or an address, and what it's the address of is the same as that other variable `i`.  And then there's also a value in the pointed-to location.  So you now have *three* things:

- the variable `ip`, and
- its value, which is "pointer to `i`", and
- the pointed-to value, which is 5.

Almost nothing gets "created on demand".  The variable `i` got created because you requested it.  The variable `ip` got created because you requested it.

You can draw a picture like this to help you keep track of things:

```
      +---------+
   i: |    5    |
      +---------+
           ^
           |
   +-------|-------+
ip:|       *       |
   +---------------+
```

The only thing that happens automatically, behind your back, that you can't necessarily see, is the assignment of some actual, numeric addresses for your variables.  You can see those if you print them out using `%p`:

```
printf("address of i: %p\n", &i);
printf("address of ip: %p\n", &ip);
```

and you will notice that `ip` holds `i`'s address:

```
printf("value of ip: %p\n", ip);
```

or you can look at everything — `i`'s two things, and `ip`'s three things — like this:

```
printf("i: loc %p, value %d\n", &i, i);
printf("ip: loc %p, value %p, pointed-to value %d\n", &ip, ip, *ip);
```

---

To see what's going on a little more explicitly, let's write this as an actual program.  For the moment, I'm going to have the variables `i` and `ip` be "global" variables, although this is unusual, because normally they'd be "local" variables, declared inside `main`.  Also I'm going to declare a third variable `j`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int i = 5;
int j = 66;
int *ip = &i;

int main()
{
    printf(" i: loc %p, value %d\n", &i, i);
    printf(" j: loc %p, value %d\n", &j, j);
    printf("ip: loc %p, value %p, pointed-to value %d\n", &ip, ip, *ip);
}
```

the output I get is

```
 i: loc 0x10837b018, value 5
 j: loc 0x10837b01c, value 66
ip: loc 0x10837b020, value 0x10837b018, pointed-to value 5
```

You'd get different addresses on your computer, but basically a similar pattern.

If you're on a Unix-like system, you can run the `nm` command to see your program's "namelist", or symbol table, which is a list of all the identifiers in your program, and their addresses.  When I run it on the program above, I get something like this:

```
$ nm a.out
000000010837b018 D _i
000000010837b01c D _j
000000010837b020 D _ip
0000000108370ec0 T _main
```

This shows me that my program has three things in the "data" segment, which are my variables, and one thing in the "text" segment, which is my `main()` function.  Lo and behold, the locations listed by the `nm` program for my two variables exactly match what was printed when the program ran.  (Although there's a complication here; see below.)

Now that we know where the variables actually are, we could draw a slightly different picture:

```
             +---------+               +---------+
  10837b018: |    5    |    10837b01c: |   66    |
             +---------+               +---------+
                  ^
                  |
          +-------|-------+
10837b020:|       *       |
          +---------------+
```

This shows us that, basically, the names or identifiers we use for things in our programs — like `i`, `j`, `ip`, and `main` — are like labels or shorthands for the addresses in memory where these things are stored.  (In fact, these identifiers are therefore kind of like pointers in their own right, although I hesitate to say this, because it might confuse the issue.)

Another way to think of it is this.  Imagine you live in a large apartment building.  In the lobby is a large row of mailboxes, one for each apartment.  Each mailbox, naturally, has a label on or next to it giving the apartment number.  So the apartment numbers are like addresses, and the contents of the mailbox are like values.

---

Finally, two footnotes.  On a modern system, the `nm` command probably *won't* print out addresses that are the same as your program did, after all, due to something called "address space randomization".

When you print pointers, strictly speaking you should cast them to `void *`, like this:

```
printf(" i: loc %p, value %d\n", (void *)&i, i);
printf("ip: loc %p, value %p, pointed-to value %d\n", (void *)&ip, (void *)ip, *ip);
```

Comment: so whenever I create a variable, something at the background automatically assigns an address to that variable's data. Since the address itself is a sequence of bits and the data is a sequence of bits as well, one sequence of bits is now pointing to another sequence of bits. Is this correct?

Comment: You can say that one sequence of bits is now pointing to another sequence of bits, yes.  The "something in the background" is actually a program called the "linker", invoked automatically by your C compiler.

Comment: I'm only saying this theoretically, but let's say 50% of the memory is allocated to actual data, like integers. Then the other 50% of the memory should contain the addresses pointing to the those 50% data, right?

Comment: No, nothing like that.  That's not the way to think of it.

Comment: You only have to allocate memory to hold an address if you declare a pointer variable in your program.  Otherwise, the addresses are just sort of "off to the side".  I'll expand the answer to explain this.

Answer (score 0):

C describes abstract machine, where pointer is pointer, and value is value (distinct from pointer).

When it comes to concrete machine, a pointer or a value may be saved in a register (which eliminates the need and the possibility of pointer to it). So you don't have infinite pointer loop, ultimately you have it in a CPU register.

When you compile your program, there may be no correspondence between C code and machine code, especially if optimizations ae enabled, so that `&a` actually may create creates no pointer (indirection optimized out), whereas `b` may create a pointer (added indirection to pass large structure).

Comment: So you're saying there is a base memory address stored at the register, that doesn't have anything else pointing to it?

Comment: Yes. Registers have "names" which are encoded as bits in executable code. Well, in a microcontroller, the registers can be implemented as pointers too. But they don't have pointers to them anyway, instead there's just a pointer to current instruction...

Answer (score 0):

You are worrying about things that the compiler handles.
When you assign a variable `a`, the compiler assigns it to a specific memory location or register - the address. The processor knows this address, and using the address, it can access the value of the variable. It doesn't need to keep a separate variable to remember the address.

There are multiple things a processor can do with the address, depending on the operations it supports, but the most common and the most relevant are direct addressing (access the value at the address number given to you in the operation), indirect addressing (access the value at the address number given to you in the operation AND THEN threat that value like an address and access ANOTHER value) and immediate addressing (treat the number given to you as a regular number). Respectively, they match `a`, `*a` and `&a` in C (this is way oversimplified though).

Conclusion - no, creating a pointer won't create an infinite amount of pointers, in order to keep track of the pointers. The processor treats everything the same - addresses are just values and values can be used as addresses.

Comment: That's essentially what I'm asking, if the processor "knows" this address, where does it store it? Surely the processor can't know something that came from thin air? It must be stored somewhere, right?

Comment: The compiler replaces the variable name with the address location it has decided on(using factors such as data alignment) and translates it to machine code. Instead of tgetting a = 4; the processor gets mov 0x2355, 0x4.

Comment: @aNoNyMoUs Technically, the address is always there. They just get variables assigned to them, not the other way around.

Comment: @aNoNyMoUs The memory map is just a linear thing. Everything in a program placed in memory has an address, which in some cases can be configured in a linker script or such. If the addresses aren't referred to by the program explicitly or implicitly, then there is no need to store them anywhere. For example variables stored on the stack are typically referred to indirectly by using the stack pointer + an address. The stack pointer being a hardware register inside the CPU.

Comment: @S.Ptr so the address( or pointer) and the data are just two random chunk of bits in memory? The compiler maps these two chunks of bits and calls one of them the address and one of them the value, right?

Comment: @aNoNyMoUs I've told you like 3 times by now that _addresses are not pointers_. I give up.

Comment: @aNoNyMoUs no, the address isnt stored in memory. Only the variable is.

Comment: @S.Ptr Where are addresses stored then, outside the memory? In CPU registors?

Comment: @aNoNyMoUs the addresses __are not stored__. They are just there. The first memory address is 0, the second is 1, the third is 2 and so on.

Comment: @Jabberwocky so you mean addresses are calculated at the software level? They don't exist at the hardware level?

Comment: @aNoNyMoUs They needn't be stored, BUT they're USED by the program counter register, memory address register and pointers - which are probably your main source of confusion. Pointers are variables that store an address. To repeat, just because they can store an address, doesn't mean they need to store it. Pointers have their own address that need not be stored, unless you explicitly want to do something like that. A good example is a linked list - which chains pointers by having them store the address of the next pointer(+ some data, which is wrapped in a struct with the pointer) in the list.

Comment: @aNoNyMoUs It's probably more complex and nuanced or even wrong on some aspect but this should be clear: Anything in memory has an address, a physical one. As said, think of it like mailboxes, and things in memory can only be stored in mailboxes. Those mailboxes have a physical address whether you want it or not. A pointer is a mailbox in which you put a paper with the address of another mailbox on it. This mailbox has an address regardless. You don't need another mailbox pointing to it for it to have an address.

Comment: @S.Ptr in the linked list example, the last node points to None or Null value. Is there any "null" equivalent in addresses?

Comment: @Uretki Yes I understood that an address needn't be stored. In your mailbox example, somebody must've created the addresses of the mailbox themselves right? By what algorithm are these mailbox addresses created?

Comment: @aNoNyMoUs it doesnt point to a null value, it points to the null address, defined in C as ((void*)0) - this means its a pointer to a unspecified type located at the 0th address. accessing that memory location (known as dereferencing) gives an error.

Comment: @aNoNyMoUs From what I understand, the OS does. To contradict what I said earlier, you don't directly use physical addresses, you use virtual addresses, and the OS provides a somewhat transparent mapping between virtual addresses and physical addresses. Those physical addresses are handled by the OS with your hardware. I can't give more details, it's beyond my knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

This minimal program

```
int r = 100;
return r;
```

generates just one instruction in main, before the `ret`:

```
mov    eax,0x64
```

There is only an immediate and a register. No address. Good nobody asked for it.

---

With `return (long)&r` it is (after some stack-checking):

```
lea    eax,[rsp+0x4]
```

Here there is no value, only the address of where one could (and would) be stored. It's a real living address, but not one containing "100".

Because C's main() returns int, the `eax` (not `rax`) is used, and the aligned half of the current stack position (`+0x4`). The version:

```
long r = 100;
return &r;
```

compiles to simply:

```
mov    eax,esp
```

(i.e. no calculation with lea needed)

To get rid of the different warnings: `return (int)(long)&r`. This probably shows that addresses are not meant to be returned outside. Here it is only done to force `-O3` to do something at all.

---

So pointers ***can*** be created on demand. But in a real program the compiler already has that address stored somewhere / in use.

---

An infinite pointer "loop" is prevented by:

```
 error: lvalue required as unary '&' operand
    6 |     return &(&r);
```

You'd have to put `&r` into a fresh variable first, before you can take it's address. Fresh variable means new name (or array index) for the programmer and a new memory address ("lvalue") for the compiler.

Answer (score 0):

This is an answer to your comment to S.Ptr answer.

The processor doesn't "know" anything.

The only thing a processor can do is execute instructions: things like "add two numbers together", "put this variable in RAM"... Before modern compiled programming languages like C all programs where created by listing instructions we wanted the processor to execute. A simple addition could have looked like this:

```
store 10 in memory at address 1
store 5 in memory at address 5

load the value at address 1 into register A
load the value at address 5 into register B
add B to A and store the result in B

store the result of B in memory at address 2
```

The programmer had to remember where they put everything because the CPU doesn't "understand" what you want it to do, it just follows your commands blindly.

As an example, let's say you made a mistake and you wrote this:

```
store 10 in memory at address 1
store 5 in memory at address 5

load the value at address 1 into register A
load the value at address 50 into register B
add B to A and store the result in B

store the result of B in memory at address 2
```

You may hope the CPU will correct you and use the right address but since it doesn't even check for this, the computer will happily run the code and add whatever was at address 50 to 10. When there's only 3 variables it's pretty easy to keep track but as you can guess, the more variables you add, the more difficult it is to remember what memory address corresponds to what data.

To help with this problem, we could use something like "address labels", basically allowing us to write the above code in this way:

```
please replace all instances of "number1" with "address 1"
please replace all instances of "number2" with "address 5"
please replace all instances of "result" with "address 2"

store 10 in memory at number1
store 5 in memory at number2

load the value at number1 into register A
load the value at number2 into register B
add B to A and store the result in B

store the result of B in memory at result
```

This way, there's no risk to use the wrong address! "number1", "number2" and "result" are meant to help the programmer so they doesn't have to remember where variables are but since the computer only understand addresses we would need to use a special software to convert the easier to understand code to instructions the machine would actually be able to run.

As time went by, we started creating more and more tools for humans to be able to write better code faster, the C programming language is one on them. Exactly like the "please replace" example, C code helps you avoid mistakes and simplifies programming a lot, at the cost of not being understood by the computer at all.

That's why you need to use a special software called a compiler to run your code, it takes your code and compiles it into the different instructions your dumb computer will execute blindly.

Through the answer I only used pseudo-code so just to get a glimpse at how things work in the real world, let's use some real C code and real CPU assembler. Here's a really simple C code to add two numbers:

```
int main()
{
    int a = 10;
    int b = 5;

    int result = a + b;

    return result;
}
```

and here's the x86_64 ASM code my compiler created from it:

```
    pushq   %rbp
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    movl    $10, -12(%rbp)
    movl    $5, -8(%rbp)
    movl    -12(%rbp), %edx
    movl    -8(%rbp), %eax
    addl    %edx, %eax
    movl    %eax, -4(%rbp)
    movl    -4(%rbp), %eax
    popq    %rbp
    ret
```

Note that the ASM listing is still not "raw", it may be a lot more difficult for us to understand than C but it's still too abstract for the CPU.

Answer (score -1):

I finally resolved my confusion(thanks to all the answers) which basically boils down to this.

In real hardware memory, there is a permanent address of each byte of data. At the software level, the operating system creates virtual addresses that map to those real addresses. It's a one-to-one mapping, for one hardware address, there is only one virtual address at a time.

In C, the compiler creates a hashmap-like data structure with variable names as keys and virtual addresses as values. For every new variable, a new entry is added to the hashmap. Whenever we want to get a virtual address of a variable, it's like asking the compiler, "hey, what is the corresponding virtual address associated with this variable name" and the compiler looks through the hashmap and returns the address corresponding to that variable name.

This is just a simplification, as the details are beyond my knowledge, but it nonetheless relieved my confusion for now.

Comment: This has some true bits in it, but it confuses the concepts of virtual memory and variable allocation and is overall incorrect. Consider that older and embedded computers have no "operating system" or "virtual memory".

Comment: @Sneftel I just wanted a nice mental model about what happens in an actual modern machine. Please feel free to add your own answer or edit mine with real facts.

Comment: But that's *not* what happens in an actual modern machine. What happens in an actual modern machine is identical to what happens in a machine without virtual memory.

Comment: As for adding my own answer, there are already a number of good answers. I suggest that you delete this one, and spend some time reading those.

Comment: "In C, the compiler creates a hashmap-like data structure with variable names as keys and virtual addresses as values" No, that's not how things work.

Comment: >Whenever we want to get a pointer of a variable, it's like asking the compiler, "hey, what is the corresponding virtual address associated with this variable name"

Still confusing pointers and addresses. You don't get a pointer of a variable, you get an address. A pointer is a variable whose value is an address of another variable.

Comment: @S.Ptr apologies, I actually meant address when I said pointer, my bad, I'm used to using those two words interchangeably